# Python: Can you find the parent class from a variable containing a function?

Tags: python, introspection

Given the following program:

```
from functools import update_wrapper                                                                                      

class MyClass:                                                                                                            
    @classmethod                                                                                                          
    def my_function(cls):                                                                                                 
        def another_function():                                                                                           
            print('hello')                                                                                                
        return update_wrapper(another_function, cls)                                                                      

def do_something(the_func):                                                                                              
    print(the_func)                                                                                                             
    # <function MyClass at 0x7f5cb69fd848>                                                                               
    print(the_func.__class__)                                                                                                   
    # <type 'function'>                                                                                                  
    print(the_func())                                                                                                     

x = MyClass()                                                                                                            
y = x.my_function()                                                                                                      

do_something(y)
```

In my do_something function, how can I identify that the 'the_func' variable came from the 'MyClass' class?  Specifically, how can I get an un-instantiated reference to MyClass?

```
print(dir(the_func))
```

...returns nothing obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `__wrapped__` dunder:

```
>>> y.__wrapped__
__main__.MyClass
```

It's [`functools.update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) that adds this attribute.

I also want to point out that your usage of `update_wrapper` is somewhat strange.  It would be more usual to use `my_function` and `another_function` here rather than `another_function` and `cls`.  Then you would access the class object through `__wrapped__` and `__self__`.

Comment: I guess my example was bad.  I have a variable containing the result of calling as_view() here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L47, but it doesn't have a __wrapped__ property.  Thanks for the pointer though, it does work with my sample app.

Answer (score 0):

when you print `the_func`, you get the function object.
So `the_func.__name__` will give you the name of that class name in which the function is wrapped!

```
from functools import update_wrapper                                                                                      

class MyClass:                                                                                                            
    @classmethod                                                                                                          
    def my_function(cls):                                                                                                 
        def another_function():                                                                                           
            print('hello')                                                                                                
        return update_wrapper(another_function, cls)                                                                      

def do_something(the_func):                                                                                              
    print(the_func)                                                                                                             
    # <function MyClass at 0x7f5cb69fd848>                                                                               
    print(the_func.__class__)                                                                                                   
    # <type 'function'>                                                                                                  
    print(the_func.__name__)                                                                                                     
    #MyClass

x = MyClass()                                                                                                            
y = x.my_function()                                                                                                      

do_something(y)
```